Unable to load data to PostgreSQL
Community,
I’m currently working on a project in the automotive sector and need the most up-to-date list of car manufacturers, along with their models and sub-models, from 1996 onwards. Specifically, I’m looking for information on European models, as my focus is on this region.
I’ve reached out to manufacturers like Mercedes-Benz, Audi, VW, and Renault, but their developer APIs are mainly focused on electric vehicles, while my project covers all models since 1996. I even requested some of them to provide a file with this data, but unfortunately, they declined.
I came across a service which offers a complete list of vehicles for $150/year. However, due to budget constraints, I’d like to explore all free options before considering this paid solution.
Any help, guidance, or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
